# @JsonView on Spring @GetMapping query parameter objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

In Spring, is it possible to use `@JsonView` on URL query parameter objects? I can do it for `@RequestBody` but we don't have bodies in GET requests. This question is specifically for URL query parameters that have been converted to objects by Spring.

For example, I want to have a controller with this mapping:

```
@GetMapping("/user") 
ResponseEntity<UserDTO> searchUser(@JsonView(value = UserView.Searchable.class) UserDTO userQuery) {
    //Do some work here using userQuery object for searching users
    return ResponseEntity.ok();
}
```

`UserDTO`:

```java
public class UserDTO {
    
    @JsonProperty("id")
    @JsonView(UserView.Private.class)
    private String id= null;

    @JsonView(UserView.Searchable.class)
    @JsonProperty("city")
    private String city = null;

    @JsonProperty("country")
    @JsonView(UserView.Searchable.class)
    private String country = null;

    @JsonProperty("state")
    private String state = null;

    @JsonProperty("zipCode")
    private String zipCode = null;
    
    //More properties and getter/setters...etc
}
```

So if I wanted to call the endpoint I could create a URL like
`localhost:8080//api/user?country=Canada` to search for a user in Canada but if I tried `localhost:8080//api/user?id=123`, the property would be ignored.

**EDIT:**
I might have rushed this idea. There is no JSON de-serialization from url parameters because they are not JSON. Spring creates the query object from `ServletModelAttributeMethodProcessor`. Perhaps if I want some custom behavior I need to implement `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` and do it myself.

**EDIT 2**
I'm a bit new to Spring so I have a lot to learn but I think what Ill do is just use `@InitBinder` to whitelist the fields for binding

```
@InitBinder
public void setSearchableFields(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.setAllowedFields(
            "city",
            "country"
            );
}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this makes the code harder to read. Just create a new `UserSearchDto` that includes only the properties that are valid for the given endpoint. Reusing code is only useful up to some point and sometimes being explicit is way better.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects, I have used a POJO just for the query params. I doubt any property would be ignored by default in spring, you can have null checks to ignore.

QueryParams.java

```
@Data
public class QueryParams {

    Integer page;
    Integer pageSize;
    String sortBy;
    Sort.Direction direction;
    String searchId;
    String status;
    String symbol;

    public PageRequest getPageRequest(){
        if(this.page==null){
            this.page = 0;
        }

        if(this.pageSize==null){
            this.pageSize = 25;
        }

        if(this.sortBy==null){
            this.sortBy = "createdAt";
        }

        if(this.direction ==null){
            this.direction = Sort.Direction.DESC;
        }

        return PageRequest.of(this.page, this.pageSize, Sort.by(this.direction, this.sortBy));
    }

}
```

And my controller :

```
@GetMapping("currencies")
public ResponseEntity<Page<CurrencyConfig>> getAllCurrencies(@Valid QueryParams queryParams) {

    try {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(orderbookService.getAllCurrencyConfig(queryParams));
    } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {
        throw new ResponseStatusException(e.getStatusCode(), e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
            e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }


}
```